# Animated View return to original rotation before another animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have an animated drawable who have tree animations: fade out, fade in and rotate.

Those three are because i change an Search drawable for a circle drawable (to indicate that the search is going on)

The problem is when i change back to "Search" drawable, he is in the same rotation of the already gone circle and after some millis he goes back to the right position.

I have tried to clearAnimations() before call the fade Out-In animations but without success.

My animations (one in each file) :
**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="800"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**fade_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="800"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

**rotate_spinner.xml**

```
 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1800"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"

   />
```

My method for change the image and handle animmations :

```
public void trocaImagemBusca(final AppCompatImageButton button, final Drawable imagemNova, final boolean animaFinal){          
       final Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_spinner);
       final Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
       final Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);


        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                button.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                button.setImageDrawable(imagemNova); // Change to the new image
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if(animaFinal) button.startAnimation(rotateAnimation); // I pass if i wanna animate after the fade in
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });


       button.startAnimation(fadeOut);

     }
```

And i cancel the search with this in another method :

```
button.clearAnimation();
trocaImagemBusca(button,buscaVermelho,false);
```

Gif to see what i mean :)

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is `onAnimationEnd` not working?

Comment: tl;dr "Animated View return to original rotation before another animation"? A: set `fillAfter` to  `true`.

Comment: @Tsangares Yes, seems to work, the animation start after the another, but the positions (rotation in the case) not come back

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto changed, same result

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto If i change in others animations, have the opposite effect, the search icon retain the position